# Change Text within a paragraph when link is clicked JQuery/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I trying to do something which I think will be simple but I can't seem to get anywhere. I have a small navigation bar with a couple of links then an area of text.  What I want to happen is when I click on a click the paragraph of text will change to the link it relates to.

I have tried the following among many things (forgive me I haven't used JQuery or javascript in quite a while) It doesn't appear to do anything whatsoever!

I am open to looking at new ways of achieving the desired effect.

```js
var ptext;

   $(document).ready(function(){
      ptext = $("#pchange");
      $(".one").click(function(){
        ptext.html("text1");
      });
      $(".two").click(function(){
        ptext.html("tex2");
   
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
header {
    background-color: #2B547E;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
}

/* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
    background: #43BFC7;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the list inside the menu */
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

article {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
section:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Style the footer */
footer {
    background-color: #2B3856;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    nav, article {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
</style>


<header>
  <h2>Voice of the Theatre</h2>
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/world_map/world_map_PNG14.png" width="100px" height="60px">
</header>

<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="one" href="#">EMEAR</a></li>
      <li><a class="two" href="#">AMER</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    
    <div id="pchange">
    
    </div>
    
<ul>
  <li>Update 1 </li>
  <li>Update 2</li>
  <li>Update 3</li>
</ul>


<h1>America</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Update 1 </li>
  <li>Update 2</li>
  <li>Update 3</li>
</ul>


  
  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: So the text is changing. Just remove `href` attribute from `a` tags and page won't be reloaded. If you want pointer on them add `cursor:pointer`

Answer (score 0):

you can either remove the href from the a tag or add `event.preventDefault()` so that the link is no longer working like it should.

also if you only want to change the text content of an element use `.text()`and not `.html()`

```js
var ptext;

$(document).ready(function() {
  ptext = $("#pchange");
  $(".one").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ptext.text("text1");
  });
  $(".two").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ptext.html("tex2");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: white;
  }
  /* Style the header */
  
  header {
    background-color: #2B547E;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
  }
  /* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
  
  nav {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
    background: #43BFC7;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  /* Style the list inside the menu */
  
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  article {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 300px;
    /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  
  section:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  /* Style the footer */
  
  footer {
    background-color: #2B3856;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
  
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    nav,
    article {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
</style>


<header>
  <h2>Voice of the Theatre</h2>
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/world_map/world_map_PNG14.png" width="100px" height="60px">
</header>

<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="one" href="#">EMEAR</a></li>
      <li><a class="two" href="#">AMER</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>

    <div id="pchange">

    </div>

    <ul>
      <li>Update 1 </li>
      <li>Update 2</li>
      <li>Update 3</li>
    </ul>


    <h1>America</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Update 1 </li>
      <li>Update 2</li>
      <li>Update 3</li>
    </ul>



  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p></p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add the **href="javascript:void(0)"** or **event.preventDefault()** or **event.preventDefault();** event.stopPropagation(); you can choose any one.

your script changes the HTML but its work **.html()** or **.text()** but **.text()** is the best beacuse text is mean the inner text html means the others element.

first, you click the **nav ul li a** button and just get this text and change your target element text.

Work fine...

**Thank you**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var ptext;

           $(document).ready(function(){
              ptext = $("#pchange");
              $("nav ul li a").click(function(event){
                ptext.html($(this).text());
              });
             
            });
    </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        h2 {
            color: white;
        }

        /* Style the header */
        header {
            background-color: #2B547E;
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 35px;
            color: white;
        }

        /* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
        nav {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
            background: #43BFC7;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        /* Style the list inside the menu */
        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        article {
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 70%;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        section:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Style the footer */
        footer {
            background-color: #2B3856;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
        }

        /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            nav, article {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
        </style>


        <header>
          <h2>Voice of the Theatre</h2>
        <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/world_map/world_map_PNG14.png" width="100px" height="60px">
        </header>

        <section>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="one" href="javascript:void(0)">EMEAR</a></li>
              <li><a class="two" href="javascript:void(0)">AMER</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          
          <article>
            <h1>London</h1>
            
            <div id="pchange">
            
            </div>
            
        <ul>
          <li>Update 1 </li>
          <li>Update 2</li>
          <li>Update 3</li>
        </ul>


        <h1>America</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Update 1 </li>
          <li>Update 2</li>
          <li>Update 3</li>
        </ul>


          
          </article>
        </section>

        <footer>
          <p></p>
        </footer>
```